# Loading data from database while working with bootstrap popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have a parent table with fields

> id | student_code | parent_name | relation | mobile | email

---

I am using codeigniter and bootstrap for my project. Currently I have loaded some detail of parent table

**In Controller**

```
$data['parents'] = $this->parent_m->get();
```

**In View**

```
<h3><span style="color:#777">Profile of</span> <?php echo $student->first_name." ".$student->middle_name . " " .$student->last_name ?></h3>
<section>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Sudent Code *</td>
        <td><?php echo $student->code; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Admission Date *</td>
        <td><?php echo $student->admission_date; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a href="#general" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#parent" data-toggle="tab">Parent Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#previous" data-toggle="tab">Previous Edu.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#result" data-toggle="tab">Result</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="general">
    <h3>General Detail</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Date of Birth *</td>
        <td><?php echo $student->dob; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td><?php echo $student->gender; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Course</td>
        <td><?php echo $student->course; ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Nationality</td>
        <td><?php echo  $student->nationality; ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Religion</td>
        <td><?php echo $student->religion; ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Current Semester </td>
        <td><?php echo $student->current_semester; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="contact">
    <h3>Contact</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Address Line 1 </td>
        <td><?php echo $student->address_line_1; ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Address Line 2</td>
        <td><?php echo $student->address_line_2; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City </td>
        <td><?php echo $student->city; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Country </td>
        <td><?php echo $student->country; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td><?php echo $student->phone; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mobile </td>
        <td><?php echo $student->mobile; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email </td>
        <td><?php echo $student->email; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="parent">
    <h3>Parent Info</h3>
    <?php if(count($parents)): ?>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Parent Name</th>
                <th>Relation</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach($parents as $parent): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $parent->parent_name; ?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $parent->relation; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    <?php else: echo "No Parent Found <br />"; endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="previous">
    <h3>Previous Education Detail</h3>
    <?php if(count($previous_details)): ?>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
        <th>Insitution Name</th>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Percentage</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($previous_details as $key): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $key->institution_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->course; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->year; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->percentage; ?></td>
        </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <?php else: echo "Previous Qualification Detail Not Added <br />"; endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="result">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Result</th>
                <th>Stream</th>
                <th>Semester</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach($exams as $exam): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $exam->title; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $exam->stream; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $exam->semester; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $exam->date; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h3>Your Parents</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
[Parent Detail Should come Here]
</div>
</div>
```

It is working fine till now. What I want now is, [content should come here] should be replace with actual content like his parent name, relation, mobile, email. There might be multiple parents in list so user can click on anyone. When user click on the parent name the parent detail should be popup on same page and it will be better if it is bootstrap popup.

Comment: Ok now I have added my view code. It is a student Profile system. I am using bootstrap tabs and populating my tabs with data from different table such are student, parent, previous education detail, result table.  A student might have many parents and I am populating parents name and relation. So What I want is when user click on the parent name it should display the whole information of the parents such as there name, mobile, email in a popup. I have created a popup with bootstrap but current it is only displaying [parent detail should be here] text. It should be replace with actual detail.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to dynamically generate the information using javascript when a user clicks on the parent.

To get the correct parent, you can add a variable to your link like this:

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" id="parentLink" data-variable = "123">
```

I would suggest using json_encode to turn your php array of parents into a json array and then you're able to access the members of that array to display in your modal. Something like this:

```
$('#parentLink').click(function(){

       var parents_info = <?php echo json_encode($parents); ?>
       var i = $(this).data("variable");

       $(.modal-body).html(parents_info[i].mobile + " " + parents_info[i].email);
    }
```